# Numbers for which Euler’s totient function equals factorial

Tags: c++

**What do you think of this solution:**

```
#define ll long long

vector<ll> p_alt;

void sieve(ll n) {

    ll* isPrime = new ll[10000001];
    ll number = n;
    ll square = (ll)(sqrt(number));
    if (n > (10000000)) n = 10000000;

    for (ll i = 2; i<= n; i++)
    {
        if (isPrime[i] == 0)
        {
            if ((number > square) && (number % (i - 1) == 0))
                p_alt.push_back(i);

            for (ll j = 2; i * j<= n; j++)
                isPrime[i * j]= 1;
        }
    }
    delete[] isPrime;
}


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    ll n = 0;
    ll q = 0;


    scanf("%lld %lld", &n, &q);
    if (!q) return 0;

    ll arr[q];
    for (ll i = 0; i<q; i++)
        scanf("%lld", &arr[i]);

    sieve(n);

    ll first = 0;
    ll second  = 0;
    long unsigned int iteratora = 0;
    long unsigned int iteratorb = 0;
    vector<ll> p_list;
    while (iteratora < p_alt.size()) {
        ll numeroo = 0;
        first = p_alt[iteratora];
        second = p_alt[iteratorb];

        if((iteratorb<p_alt.size()))
            ++iteratorb;
        else {
            ++iteratora;
            iteratorb = 0;
        }
        //mult = first*second;
        numeroo = (first - 1 )*(second - 1 );
        if (numeroo == n) {
            p_list.push_back(first*second);
        }
    }
    sort(p_list.begin(), p_list.end());

    for (int n : arr){
        if (n + 1 < p_list.size())
            printf("%lld\n",p_list[n]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to solve a inverse euler function as adapted from euler 248 in [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler248/problem).

I don't completely understand the question and not sure I'm doing it right, but also the test cases are hidden, so not sure what's wrong with my code.

I am using the formula of having the prime number n  and the n - 1 as divisor of the factorial. Works the first input case, as:

```
6227020800 1
1
```

Not sure about the others

Comment: `#define ll unsigned long long` Ugh! Aargh! Eek!

Comment: A good first step would probably be to understand the question.

Comment: Try some more basic test cases. `1 2 1 2` should produce 1 and 2 (phi(1) is 1 and phi(2) are both 1); `2 2 1 2` should be 3 and 4 (phi(3) and phi(4) are both 2), but your program produces no output at all.

Comment: "The first number  for which   phi(n) = 13! is 6227180929 .
Perform several queries each of which is to find the -th number  for which . phi(n) = m"

Comment: Project Euler #248: Numbers for which Euler’s totient function equals 13!

Comment: So I assumed as input I have a factorial number

Comment: "The first line of each test file contains two integers separated by single spaces, which are m and q, where q is the number of queries. q lines follow, each containing the corresponding k."

Comment: In the outer ``for`` loop ``i`` can reach ``10000001``, so ``isPrime[i]`` will read past the end of the array. Also, ``ll arr[q]`` is not valid C++, use a vector instead.

Comment: @MarcoSavo The input is some arbitrary number. You're reading too much into the example of 13!.